# unable to get full screen display in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have just updated to Xcode 6 and every time I create a new Sprite Kit project, I run it on my iPhone 5s and the display does not reach the top and bottom of the screen. It is blacked out for about 1cm each at the top and bottom of the screen. I can't figure out why. Previous projects that I have made still work fine, its just these new ones that don't.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it's about having not complete set of the launching images. Remove all launching images (all sizes: iPhone 4, iPhone 5 and iPad) OR add ALL sizes. I had similar issue when I added only iPhone 4 size to my project in Xcode.